# Internal Error: DBG2439 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, testcomplete

I am building a project in Delphi 5. I have successully builded the project and genrated the output exe. Till this state everything works fine. Now I am using testing automation tool 'TestComplete' on the generated the exe. But in TestComplete only Published properties are visible. I am unable to see the private and public properties. TestComplete documentation suggested a way to build the exe with Debug option checked. For that i modified the setting in Project--> Options --> Linker --> Exe and DLL options --> Include TD32 Debug Info is checked and trying to build the project but I am getting an "[Fatal Error]Internal error: DBG2439". I tried closing the delphi and opening the project again. Also I tried deleting all DCUs. But getting same error everytime.
Can Anybody help me on this. Thanks For the help.

Testcomplete link or reference: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/29770/

Got one link while googling but didnt understand steps. can anyone help me to understand. Its really appriciated.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/borland.public.delphi.ide/PDJUVyFbfQ8/huCmBa3eCVIJ

Comment: What did Smartbear say when you asked them? Do they even support Delphi 5 which is now 13 years old?

Comment: its not mentioned anything about Delphi 5 but i tried another module with same process and I am able to build with that Include TD32 Debug Info option checked in.

Comment: This question doesn't really belong here on SO. It's either a Smartbear support question (regarding TestComplete) or an actual compiler error (in which case you're out of luck, since Delphi 5 is more than a decade out of support) - internal compiler errors are just that: errors internal to the compiler, and the error message is only of meaning to the compiler developers. (DBG is definitely related to the debugger portion of the compiler, but the 2439 is meaningless without access to the source code of the D5 compiler. )

Comment: Agree - the question is not related to TestComplete, since you are having problems with the compiler, and not with TestComplete itself. If you can't build the app with debug information, that's not a good thing itself. What I would try include: trying to use an older Windows version, reinstalling the IDE, trying to modify other compiler options like those related to optimization (there may be a specific configuration that works), trying to exclude files/modules from the Delphi project to see if there is a specific file that causes the debug info compiler to break.

Comment: As for the TestComplete part of the question: if you can't resolve the compiler problem, consider extending the needed classes with published properties, so you get the needed functionality for your test automation. Another option here is changing the window procedure of the app's main form to use window messages to access some data - you send a custom message (WM_USER+X) to the window from your TestComplete script (it is possible to do this through Win32API.SendMessage in TC), and read the result from a parameter. I hope this helps with your testing.

Comment: Try [these tips](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/InternalErrors.ashx), e.g. building from the command line using dcc32.exe.

Comment: Tried all above ways.. No success yet.. :( :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally able to resolve the error. :)

The dbg3439 and dbg 2499 error was due to ResourceString declaration after subprocedure.

Please refer the link for more help: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/borland.public.delphi.ide/PDJUVyFbfQ8/huCmBa3eCVIJ

Thanks to all..